# CSS: Opaque overlay with transparent div sections

Tags: css, transparency

I'm developing a help system for a site where they want the page to turn opaque when activated except for the DIVs you can receive help on.

The problem is I can't figure out how to get specific divs to "appear" transparent on top of an opaque background.

I tried setting the z-index of the divs to a value higher than the background but that doesnt seem to work.

Here is a JSBin illustrating the issue.  Anything with the "help" class should appear to be transparent (i.e. not opaque)

http://jsbin.com/ifohuc/1/edit

Thanks.

Comment: I personally prefer to use 1px x 1px transparent .png files as background-image on the divs. Otherwise, you also run into trouble with the text being transparent. There are ways around this, but if you don't need to regularly change the div color, I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the position attribute of li.help in the css file

for example

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: I agree with `@fa7d0` and this is because the `z-index` property only works when an element is set to `position: absolute;` or in this case it will work with `position: relative` I just tried with your JSBin and it worked perfect after adding `position: relative` to your `li.help`

Answer (score 0):

Change `#bgDiv` to `z-index= -1`

http://jsbin.com/ifohuc/2/

```
#bgDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #999999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.85;
  z-index: -1;
}
```