# When I click on any div, only that div have to come up and rest all contents of page should be in Overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I have a situation some thing like this

```
<div id="my div">
    <div>
       content of div 1
    </div>
    <div>
       content of div 2
    </div>
    <div>
       content of div 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Out of those three div's if I click on any one of them, only that particular div(which I clicked) have to come up affront and rest of all the page should display in background as overlay.

Along with this I should be able to drag that highlighted div on that overlay background to where ever I want.

Can any one suggest me some solution in doing this....

Comment: You can achieve this with Javascript or Jquery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: I don't want to hide my rest of page contents, it should display in background just like when alert pop up is displayed.

Comment: did my answer helped you @John Krishna ??

Comment: No Anurag,
Actually I need some thing like to shown only that particular div in active and rest of the page should be in-active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fa7d0/BqsdE/

you could set the opacity of the other two divs (for example 0.2)

javascript:

```
$("#div1").click(function(){
    $("#div2").css('opacity','0.2');
    $("#div3").css('opacity','0.2');
});
$("#div2").click(function(){
    $("#div1").css('opacity','0.2');
    $("#div3").css('opacity','0.2');
});
$("#div3").click(function(){
    $("#div2").css('opacity','0.2');
    $("#div1").css('opacity','0.2');
});

$(".div").each(function(){ //reset all
    $(this).css('opacity','1.0');
});
```

html:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<div id='div1' class='div'>
   content of div 1
</div>
<div id='div2' class='div'>
   content of div 2
</div>
<div id='div3' class='div'>
   content of div 3
</div>
</div>
```

**you can use the reset all function for example when the use clicks out of the three divs**

Comment: Opacity in the sense, it will just decrease opacity but it won't make rest of page inactive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817962/css-opaque-overlay-with-transparent-div-sections/17818221#17818221

Comment: if you create a div-overlay, the rest of the page will be inactive: http://jsfiddle.net/fa7d0/qSndv/

Comment: Ya it helped me to get some logic, which is almost familiar kind of thing.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) .
Also see this [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/) page for your help .
For dragging see this [page](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) , it has helped me really .
This is the source code **form that site** : -

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-   ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
 <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

For Zooming a div use this : -

```
 #div_id:hover 
 {
  zoom:30%;
  }
```

Also see this [page](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/).

Comment: Ya draggable is ok, but still I am unable to figure it out how to bring only one div to front among them and rest of page in overlay.

Comment: Sorry far, zoom is not suitable for my requierment.